# Conditional fill of columns in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause, apply, fill

This question is similar to a few questions regarding conditionally filling. I'm trying to conditionally fill the column based off the following statements.

If the value in `Code` starts with `A`, I want to keep the values as they are.

If the value `Code` starts with `B`, I want to keep the same initial value and return `nan's` to the following rows until the next value in `Code`.

If the value in `Code` starts with `C`, I want to keep the same first value until the next floats in `['Numx','Numy]`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


d = ({                          
      'Code' :['A1','A1','','B1','B1','A2','A2','','B2','B2','','A3','A3','A3','','B1','','B4','B4','A2','A2','A1','A1','','B4','B4','C1','C1','','','D1','','B2'],
      'Numx' : [30.2,30.5,30.6,35.6,40.2,45.5,46.1,48.1,48.5,42.2,'',30.5,30.6,35.6,40.2,45.5,'',48.1,48.5,42.2, 40.1,48.5,42.2,'',48.5,42.2,43.1,44.1,'','','','',45.1],
      'Numy' : [1.9,2.3,2.5,2.2,2.5,3.1,3.4,3.6,3.7,5.4,'',2.3,2.5,2.2,2.5,3.1,'',3.6,3.7,5.4,6.5,8.5,2.2,'',8.5,2.2,2.3,2.5,'','','','',3.2]
      })
```

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

Output:

```
   Code  Numx Numy
0    A1  30.2  1.9
1    A1  30.5  2.3
2        30.6  2.5
3    B1  35.6  2.2
4    B1  40.2  2.5
5    A2  45.5  3.1
6    A2  46.1  3.4
7        48.1  3.6
8    B2  48.5  3.7
9    B2  42.2  5.4
10        nan  nan       
11   A3  30.5  2.3
12   A3  30.6  2.5
13   A3  35.6  2.2
14       40.2  2.5
15   B1  45.5  3.1
16        nan  nan     
17   B4  48.1  3.6
18   B4  48.5  3.7
19   A2  42.2  5.4
20   A2  40.1  6.5
21   A1  48.5  8.5
22   A1  42.2  2.2
23        nan  nan      
24   B4  48.5  8.5
25   B4  42.2  2.2
26   C1  43.1  2.3
27   C1  44.1  2.5
28        nan  nan      
29        nan  nan   
30   D1   nan  nan      
31        nan  nan        
32   B2  45.1  3.2
```

I have used code posted from another question but I return too many Nan's

```
df['Code_new'] = df['Code'].where(df['Code'].isin(['A1','A2','A3','A4','B1','B2','B4','C1'])).ffill()

df[['Numx','Numy']] = df[['Numx','Numy']].mask(df['Code_new'].duplicated())
mask = df['Code_new'] == 'A1'
df.loc[mask, ['Numx','Numy']] = df.loc[mask, ['Numx','Numy']].ffill()
```

This produces this output:

```
   Code  Numx Numy Code_new
0    A1  30.2  1.9       A1
1    A1  30.2  1.9       A1
2        30.2  1.9       A1
3    B1  35.6  2.2       B1
4    B1   NaN  NaN       B1
5    A2  45.5  3.1       A2
6    A2   NaN  NaN       A2
7         NaN  NaN       A2
8    B2  48.5  3.7       B2
9    B2   NaN  NaN       B2
10        NaN  NaN       B2
11   A3  30.5  2.3       A3
12   A3   NaN  NaN       A3
13   A3   NaN  NaN       A3
14        NaN  NaN       A3
15   B1   NaN  NaN       B1
16        NaN  NaN       B1
17   B4  48.1  3.6       B4
18   B4   NaN  NaN       B4
19   A2   NaN  NaN       A2
20   A2   NaN  NaN       A2
21   A1  30.2  1.9       A1
22   A1  30.2  1.9       A1
23       30.2  1.9       A1
24   B4   NaN  NaN       B4
25   B4   NaN  NaN       B4
26   C1  43.1  2.3       C1
27   C1   NaN  NaN       C1
28        NaN  NaN       C1
29        NaN  NaN       C1
30   D1   NaN  NaN       C1
31        NaN  NaN       C1
32   B2   NaN  NaN       B2
```

My desired output would be:

```
   Code  Numx Numy
0    A1  30.2  1.9
1    A1  30.5  2.3
2        30.6  2.5
3    B1  35.6  2.2
4    B1   nan  nan
5    A2  45.5  3.1
6    A2  46.1  3.4
7        48.1  3.6
8    B2  48.5  3.7
9    B2   nan  nan
10        nan  nan        
11   A3  30.5  2.3
12   A3  30.6  2.5
13   A3  35.6  2.2
14       40.2  2.5
15   B1  45.5  3.1
16        nan  nan         
17   B4  48.1  3.6
18   B4   nan  nan
19   A2  42.2  5.4
20   A2  40.1  6.5
21   A1  48.5  8.5
22   A1  42.2  2.2
23        nan  nan      
24   B4  48.5  8.5
25   B4   nan  nan
26   C1  43.1  2.3
27   C1  43.1  2.3
28       43.1  2.3   
29       43.1  2.3   
30   D1  43.1  2.3   
31       43.1  2.3         
32   B2  45.1  3.2
```

I think this this line `mask = df['Code_new'] == 'A1'` I need to change. The code works but I'm only applying to to the values in code that are `'A1'`. Is as easy as adding all the other values in here. So `A1-A4,B1-B4,C1`?

Comment: Can you reduce the dataframe to a minimum of  lines (5-6), so that it is possible to grasp what is right or wrong with your substitution rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need

```
m2 = df['Code'].isin(['A1','A2','A3','A4','B1','B2','B4','C1'])

#create helper column for unique categories
df['Code_new'] = df['Code'].where(m2).ffill()
df['Code_new'] = (df['Code_new'] + '_' + 
                  df['Code_new'].ne(df['Code_new'].shift()).cumsum().astype(str))

#check by start values and filter all columns without A
m1 = df['Code_new'].str.startswith(tuple(['A1','A2','A3','A4'])).fillna(False)
df[['Numx','Numy']] = df[['Numx','Numy']].mask(df['Code_new'].duplicated() & ~m1)

#replace by forward filling only starting with C
mask = df['Code_new'].str.startswith('C').fillna(False)
df.loc[mask, ['Numx','Numy']] = df.loc[mask, ['Numx','Numy']].ffill()

print (df)
```

---

```
   Code  Numx Numy Code_new
0    A1  30.2  1.9     A1_1
1    A1  30.5  2.3     A1_1
2        30.6  2.5     A1_1
3    B1  35.6  2.2     B1_2
4    B1   NaN  NaN     B1_2
5    A2  45.5  3.1     A2_3
6    A2  46.1  3.4     A2_3
7        48.1  3.6     A2_3
8    B2  48.5  3.7     B2_4
9    B2   NaN  NaN     B2_4
10        NaN  NaN     B2_4
11   A3  30.5  2.3     A3_5
12   A3  30.6  2.5     A3_5
13   A3  35.6  2.2     A3_5
14       40.2  2.5     A3_5
15   B1  45.5  3.1     B1_6
16        NaN  NaN     B1_6
17   B4  48.1  3.6     B4_7
18   B4   NaN  NaN     B4_7
19   A2  42.2  5.4     A2_8
20   A2  40.1  6.5     A2_8
21   A1  48.5  8.5     A1_9
22   A1  42.2  2.2     A1_9
23                     A1_9
24   B4  48.5  8.5    B4_10
25   B4   NaN  NaN    B4_10
26   C1  43.1  2.3    C1_11
27   C1  43.1  2.3    C1_11
28       43.1  2.3    C1_11
29       43.1  2.3    C1_11
30   D1  43.1  2.3    C1_11
31       43.1  2.3    C1_11
32   B2  45.1  3.2    B2_12
```

Comment: It works on my dummy data but I'm getting a `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'` on my dataset on the `df[['Numx','Numy']] = df[['Numx','Numy']].mask(df['Code_new'].duplicated() & ~m1)`. My actual dataset contains values with space. e.g `Free Kick`. Will that affect the code?

Comment: @Maxibon - it means there are `NaN`s, are real data confidental?

Comment: @Maxibon - Try `df[['Numx','Numy']].mask(df['Code_new'].duplicated() & ~(m1).fillna(False))`

Comment: That doesn't fill `C` down on my dummy data and I'm getting a `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values` on my actual data

Comment: hmm, so `27.row` down are nort replaced? like in my answer?

Comment: I have idea - for `str.startswith` was added `.fillna(False)`

Comment: What about `mask - mask.fillna(False), df.loc[mask, ['Numx','Numy']] = df.loc[mask, ['Numx','Numy']].ffill()` ?

Comment: Brilliant @jezrael. Thanks so much